# Make a prolog BST from a list and return it in the parameter

Tags: tree, prolog

I need to make a prolog predicate `from_list/2` so that if i call `from_list([], T)` I will get back a tree containg the items in the list(ints) so far I have:

```
from_list([], empty).
from_list([X], T) :-
    insert(X, empty, T).
from_list([X|Y], T) :-
    from_list(Y, NT),
    insert(X, NT, T).
```

edit: figured it out, but it is adding them to the tree in reverse order of the list. Any help?

Here is my insert predicate, which seems to work just fine.

```
insert( X, empty, bt(X, empty, empty) ). 
insert( X, bt(X2, L, R), bt(X2, NL, R) ) :-
    X < X2,
    !,
    insert(X, L, NL). 
insert( X, bt(X2, L, R), bt(X2, L, NR) ):-
    insert(X, R, NR).
```

And not also a second, much smaller question which doesn't NEED an answer

I know prolog has a very elegant style when used properly...and this code...not so elegant...

```
is_search(empty).
is_search( bt(_, empty, empty) ).
is_search( bt( X, empty, bt(Y,LEFT,RIGHT) ) ) :-
    X < Y,
    is_search(LEFT),
    is_search(RIGHT).
is_search( bt(X, bt(Y,LEFT,RIGHT), empty) ) :-
    X > Y,
    is_search(LEFT),
    is_search(RIGHT).
is_search( bt( X, bt(Y,L1,R1), bt(Z, L2, R2) ) ) :-
    X > Y,
    X < Z,
    is_search( bt(Y, L1, R1) ),
    is_search( bt(Z, L2, R2) ).
```

Any tips on how to clean that up a little?

Comment: please try to indent your code yourself next time!

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint from my side:

```
from_list([], empty).
from_list([X], T):- insert(X, empty, T).
from_list([X|Y], T):- from_list(Y, NT), insert(X, NT, T).
```

This will not work because if you´re looking at line 2 empty is not known.

To have a list in reverse order use

```
reverse(X,R).
```

PS: As far as i can see we are talking of SWI-Prolog, right?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question, I would say you should describe the TWO (not five!) cases of a binary tree: Either it is empty, or it is an inner node where all the elements to the left and right are smaller and larger, respectively, and are binary trees themselves:

```
bt(empty).
bt(bt(Val, Left, Right)) :-
    all_smaller_than(Left, Val),
    all_larger_than(Right, Val),
    bt(Left),
    bt(Right).
```

I leave all_smaller_than/2 and all_larger_than/2 as an exercise for you. Hint: Again two clauses suffice for each of them. You may find a way to make it faster as well...